# How to fix middleware typescript error when creating a new req param

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware where I check if a bearer token exists and then if the token exists I make a database call and get user information. If I get the information I want to put that into a new variable like "req.user". But I got this error:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
```

The Error is clear but idk how to fix it

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { supabase } from '../server.js';

export const verifyJWT = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    // get the bearer token from the header
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];

    // check if the bearer token exists
    if(!bearerHeader) {
      throw new Error('Die Anfrage konnte wegen einem ungültigen oder fehlerhaften Token nicht verarbeitet werden. Wenden Sie sich an den Support.');
    }

    // Split the token where there is a empty space and then we get an array of all founded values
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');

    // the token is in the second value from the array 
    const token = bearer[1];
    
    const user = await supabase.auth.getUser(token);

    if(!user) {
      throw new Error('Es wurde kein Nutzer gefunden. Bitte wenden Sie sich an den Support.');
    }

    req.user = user;
    
    next();
  } catch(e) {
    if(e instanceof Error) {
      Sentry.captureException(e.message);
      console.log(e);
      return res.status(500).json({message: e.message});
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({message: e});
    }
  }
};
```

PS: The error is at req.user = user